# Digitize vinyl on PC (TT > Stereo Amp > USB Audio Interface > PC recording software)

Tags: digital, conversion, signal-processing, analog

Never tried anything like this, so please excuse any inevitable incompetence!

I'm trying to rip vinyl records from my turntable to my computer. Here's the relevant (I think) equipment I've got:

- JVC QL-F4 (No preamp, moving magnet cartridge)
- Marantz PM6003 (Moving magnet phono stage)
- Behringer UMC202HD (Inputs: XLR/TRS combo)

I think all I'm missing is a 2 x RCA to 2 x 6.35mm (1/4") jack cable, for connecting my amp's output to my USB audio interface. (If I'm wrong, I'd love to know)

A friend of mine raised concerns over the audio interface's capability of receiving amplified signals from the amp, as it's designed for receiving line level inputs (essentially, he's worried I'll fry my interface).

Is this something I should be concerned about? I'd prefer not to have to purchase additional equipment if possible.

Thanks for any time taken reading this!

Comment: Use one of the Recorder outs to the Behringer. Don't expect miracles; unless it's rare vinyl you'll get better results from iTunes/Spotify.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you! I know it's probably obvious, but a 2 x RCA to 2 x 6.35mm (1/4") should be fine for this purpose, correct? And seeing how technical more experienced people are getting with a process like this, I'm not expecting anything exceptional from my low-end equipment - but I can't find the album online anywhere.

Comment: If the plugs fit, you're half way there. idk the Behringer, but check if the input is switchable, mic/line/inst. One of those will be the best impedance match. Theoretically 'line' but consumer to semi-pro gear is often just a try-it-and-see-which-is-best.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks again. If you'd like to post your comments as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Marantz as your pre-amp. Route the audio out of one of its 'Recorder' outputs. This should give you consumer-level output, nominally -20dB.
Input to the Behringer on a switchable input mic/line/instrument & flick between the options to see which gives you the best impedance/level match - probably line or instrument. Watch levels as you do this, start with any variable pot set at minimum & hope to get decent levels around halfway on the gain.

It's all a bit of guesswork, as they're not really designed to work together, but you should be able to get something approximating a decent signal from one of the settings.